# Navigation jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code :

```js
$('.category').hide();
  $('.category').first().show();

 $('.inline-title a').first().addClass('active');


  $('.category .inline-subtitles a:first-child').addClass('active');

  //Category
  $(".inline-title a[data-toggle]").on("click", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating
     var selector = $(this).data("toggle"); // get corresponding element
     $(".category").hide();
     $("."+selector).show();
     $('.category .inline-subtitles a:first-child').addClass('active');
        $(".inline-title .active").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
 });

  $('.document').hide();
  $('.documents-75 .document').first().show();
  $('.documents-76 .document').first().show();

  $('category:first-child .documents document').first().show();
  $('category:nth-child(n+2) .documents document').first().show();

  //SubCategory
  $(".inline-subtitles a[data-toggle]").on("click", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating
     var selector = $(this).data("toggle"); // get corresponding element
     $(".document").hide();
     $("."+selector).show();
     $('.category .inline-subtitles a:first-child').removeClass('active');
        $(".inline-subtitles .active").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
 });
```

```css
.bloc-documentation {
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.inline-title,
.inline-subtitles {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 10px;


 border-top: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.inline-title a,
.inline-subtitles a {
 display: table-cell;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 25px;
 padding-top: 5px;

 color: #192f3c;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 300;
 
 text-decoration: none;
 border-top: 2px solid transparent;

 -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: color .2s ease-out;
 transition: color .2s ease-out;
}

.inline-title .active,
.inline-subtitles .active {
 border-top: 2px solid #9dad3e;
}

.inline-title a:hover {
 color: #9dad3e;
}


.inline-title:after {
 clear:both;
 content:'';
 display: table;
}

.active {
 display: inline-block !important;
}


.category:first-child {
 padding-top: 0;
}

.category {
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 padding-top: 15px;
}

.category h3 {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bloc-documentation">
<div class="inline-title">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-75">Volets roulants</a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-76">Porte de garage</a>
</div>
<div class="category cat-75">
    <div class="inline-subtitles">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-doc-technique">Doc technique</a>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-carnet-utilisateur">Carnet utilisateur</a>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-notice-de-pose">Notice de pose</a>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-notice-reglages">Notice reglages</a>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-nomenclatures">Nomenclatures</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="category cat-76">
    <div class="inline-subtitles">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-doc-technique" class="active">Doc technique</a>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-carnet-utilisateur">Carnet utilisateur</a>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-notice-de-pose">Notice de pose</a>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-notice-reglages">Notice reglages</a>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-nomenclatures">Nomenclatures</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

It almost work, but here's my problem ... : When you click on a random link in the category **"Volets roulants"**, then go to the main link called **"Porte de garage"**. Finally go to the main link **"Volets roulants"** and you'll see two links are overlined.

I try to fix this issue but it does not work.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

When you first chose a sub-item under "Volets roulants", that sub-item was given the `active` class.

When you return to that category, it sets `active` on the `a:first-child` sub-item, but never removes the `active` class where it may have been set before.

Add this:

```
$('.category .inline-subtitles a').removeClass('active');
```

before

```
$('.category .inline-subtitles a:first-child').addClass('active');
```

```js
$('.category').hide();
$('.category').first().show();

$('.inline-title a').first().addClass('active');


$('.category .inline-subtitles a:first-child').addClass('active');

//Category
$(".inline-title a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating
  var selector = $(this).data("toggle"); // get corresponding element
  $(".category").hide();
  $("." + selector).show();
  $('.category .inline-subtitles a').removeClass('active');
  $('.category .inline-subtitles a:first-child').addClass('active');
  $(".inline-title .active").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.document').hide();
$('.documents-75 .document').first().show();
$('.documents-76 .document').first().show();

$('category:first-child .documents document').first().show();
$('category:nth-child(n+2) .documents document').first().show();

//SubCategory
$(".inline-subtitles a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating
  var selector = $(this).data("toggle"); // get corresponding element
  $(".document").hide();
  $("." + selector).show();
  $('.category .inline-subtitles a:first-child').removeClass('active');
  $(".inline-subtitles .active").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.bloc-documentation {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.inline-title,
.inline-subtitles {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
.inline-title a,
.inline-subtitles a {
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #192f3c;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease-out;
  transition: color .2s ease-out;
}
.inline-title .active,
.inline-subtitles .active {
  border-top: 2px solid #9dad3e;
}
.inline-title a:hover {
  color: #9dad3e;
}
.inline-title:after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
.active {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
.category:first-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}
.category {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.category h3 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bloc-documentation">
  <div class="inline-title">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-75">Volets roulants</a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-76">Porte de garage</a>
  </div>
  <div class="category cat-75">
    <div class="inline-subtitles">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-doc-technique">Doc technique</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-carnet-utilisateur">Carnet utilisateur</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-notice-de-pose">Notice de pose</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-notice-reglages">Notice reglages</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-nomenclatures">Nomenclatures</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="category cat-76">
    <div class="inline-subtitles">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-doc-technique" class="active">Doc technique</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-carnet-utilisateur">Carnet utilisateur</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-notice-de-pose">Notice de pose</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-notice-reglages">Notice reglages</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="wpcf-nomenclatures">Nomenclatures</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah I got it ! Thanks for the help